# How to use python Popen with a espeak and aplay

Tags: python, asynchronous, popen, espeak

I'm trying to call

```
espeak -ves -s130 'HEY' --stdout | aplay -D 'sysdefault'
```

through subprocess.Popen, with

```
espeak_process = Popen(["espeak", "-ves -s100 'HEY' --stdout"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
aplay_process = Popen(["aplay", "-D 'sysdefault'"], stdin=espeak_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But it doesn't work

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM  'sysdefault'
aplay: main:682: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to implement this?
Thx

Comment: Yes, it works like a charm, BIG THANKS :) *If you answer as a question I'll marked that as the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is the equivalent of typing this in the shell:

```
$ espeak '-ves -s100 \'HEY\' --stdout'
$ aplay '-D \'sysdefault\''
```

Which is obviously wrong. Each list entry is one argument (argv entry) passed to the executable, no escaping/quoting needed on your side. So you want to use:

```
["aplay", "-D", "sysdefault"]
["espeak", "-ves", "-s100", "HEY", "--stdout"],
```

Also see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) (emphasis mine):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence of program arguments. **Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names)**. If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed without specifying any arguments.