# Convert python espeak + subprocess code to play output audio directly

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, alsa, espeak

I'm using an existing program that reads xml from a socket, converts text to a wav file and then plays it over the audio output device.

I'd like to strip it down so it just plays the text direct to audio.

Right now I'm having a difficult time figuring out if I've got the correct code and understanding if it's actually creating the wav file.

**Function that calls calls the text to speech function**

```
def generate_audio(self, language, voice=None):
    info = self.get_first_info(language, bestmatch=False)
    if info is None:
        self.media_info[language] = None
        return False

    truncate = not self.broadcast_immediately() and bcastplayer.Config.setting('alerts_truncate')
    message_text = info.get_message_text(truncate)

    location = bcastplayer.ObData.get_datadir() + "/alerts"
    if os.access(location, os.F_OK) == False:
        os.mkdir(location)
    filename = self.reference(self.sent, self.identifier) + "-" + language + ".wav"

    resources = info.get_resources('audio')
    if resources:
        if resources[0].write_file(os.path.join(location, filename)) is False:
            return False

    elif message_text:
        self.write_tts_file(os.path.join(location, filename), message_text, voice)

    else:
        return False
```

**Can this be modified to play the audio directly?**

```
def write_tts_file(self, path, message_text, voice=None):
    if not voice:
        voice = 'en'
    proc = subprocess.Popen([ 'espeak', '-m', '-v', voice, '-s', '130', '--stdout' ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
    (stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate(message_text.encode('utf-8') + b" <break time=\"2s\" /> " + message_text.encode('utf-8') + b" <break time=\"3s\" /> ")
    proc.wait()

    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(stdout)
```

I've never seen code like this using `process`, `subprocess`, `stdout`, `PIPE`.

Is it easy to change the subprocess code to something that just pipes or redirects the output to `aplay` without creating the wav file?

There was another answer that might give a clue - but again, my newbie understanding isn't sure how to convert this code to that answer

[How to use python Popen with a espeak and aplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912586/how-to-use-python-popen-with-a-espeak-and-aplay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link the two processes together using `subprocess.PIPE`. Here is a modified version of the `write_tts_file` function:

```
def write_tts_file(self, path, message_text, voice=None):
    if not voice:
        voice = 'en'
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['espeak', '-m', '-v', voice, '-s', '130', '--stdout' ], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)
    aplay = subprocess.Popen(['aplay', '-D', 'sysdefault'], stdin=proc.stdout)
    proc.stdin.write(message_text.encode('utf-8') + b" <break time=\"2s\" /> " + message_text.encode('utf-8') + b" <break time=\"3s\" /> \n")
    proc.stdin.close()
    proc.wait()
```

It is important to close the `proc`'s `stdin` after you have sent the message that is to be spoken. This will make `proc` quit when it has sent its data, and close its output to `aplay`, which in turn will quit when it has finished playing. If `proc`'s input isn't closed, neither of them will quit.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try. I really have a hard time understandiing espeak and subprocesses